# Can a module be run with option -m from another folder which is not its parent?

Tags: python, bash, python-module

When running a Python module (inside a package) I always use the option -m from the parent folder.

Let's suppose that we have the following directory of files:

```
folder-that-contains-root-project-folder/
    root-project-folder/
        package/
            __init__.py
            module.py
            venv/
```

I always run module.py from the folder ***`root-project-folder`*** as `python -m package.module` and it works.

But how could I run module.py from ***`folder-that-contains-root-project-folder`***? What I tried so far is `python -m root-project-folder/package.module` but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** The error when running from **`folder-that-contains-root-project-folder`** is:

```
/home/eduardo/Desktop/folder-that-contains-root-project-folder/root-project-folder/venv/bin/python:
Error while finding module specification for
'root-project-folder/package.module' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module
named 'root-project-folder/package')
```

**PD:** I'm using bash on Ubuntu

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What was the output after running that command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions here:

1. Run `python -m root-project-folder.package.module`. Basically, you treat `rood-project-folder` as a module and use `.` to separate the folders rather than `/` just like you do in Python code.
2. Add `root-project-folder` to `PYTHONPATH`. Now you will be able to run `python -m package.module` as usual from any folder on your machine.

Comment: Well it works but when the executed module has another dependencies (imported modules) from another packages it does not work.

Comment: @EduardoG Which option did you try?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need toml or setup.py in your package for generating a python package. You can read more here: `https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/`
2. Once you have package folder constructed properly, you can run the command
   `pip install -e .` from the folder to install your package
3. Your package is ready to be imported/deployed
4. How to delpoy to PyPi is another topic of discussion

Comment: This only explains how to create a package and then install it in another project. This doesn't say anything about just running the code from another folder.